# Are Freeletics and Crossfit the same thing?

Tags: crossfit

I am confused on what the two are. I know the concept is working out without equipment in a high intensity fashion, but more than that, I am lost.

Comment: I am unsure, but I tend to consider Freeletics as a subset of Crossfit.

Answer (score 6):

Freeletics is basically CrossFit for the bodyweight exercises. It doesn't have as big of a following, but Freeletics originated in Germany. Instead of it being a lifestyle as CF is, the program is for generally 15 weeks of hard exercises. If you get the Coach, it will tell you what to do throughout the week. If not and you want all the exercises, I recommend buying the Freeletics Pro app, which is about 5 bucks. Well worth it, since you can work out anywhere and not have to pay the expensive gym fees that CF is known for.

Comment: This answer may need an update. Freeletics has grown considerably, both in scope and numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Both systems propose high-intensity workouts targeting all aspects of phyical fitness. The differences are more in the business model.

**Crossfit**

- Uses weights and other equipment.
- Gym-based.
- Certified trainers help you along.

**Freeletics**

- Bodyweight only (some equipment still required).
- Community-based.
- Fellow athletes and a (free¹) mobile app help you along.

So, if you have the money and need the extrinsical motivation of a gym and trainers, Crossfit may be your thing. If you require independence and low cost, Freeletics can work for you.

---

1. The full set of exercises/workouts and personalized training schedules are not free.